# Unable to copy local Python file to HIVE using terminal

Tags: python, hive, hdfs, user-defined-functions

I am trying to upload a Python file (for UDF) from my local Downloads folder onto HIVE but had no success. I used the command:

```
scp -P 2222 ~/Downloads/geohash-udf.py root@localhost:/root/;
```

However, I got the following error messages:

[image]

I've also tried adding the file directly from my local directory by running the following command:

```
hive> add file /Users/Shaolun/Downloads/geohash-udf.py;
```

But I got this error:

```
Query returned non-zero code: 1, cause: /Users/Shaolun/Downloads/geohash-udf.py does not exist.
```

I had also tried to put the file into HDFS first and then get the file from HDFS using the following command:

```
hive> add file hdfs:///user/root/geohash-udf.py;
```

The command worked as expected. But I don't want this because I want to be able to have HIVE grab the Python file from my local Windows machine not from HDFS.

The exact local path of my Python file is 'C:/Users/Shaolun/Downloads/geohash-udf.py', and my OS is Windows 10. I am confused as to why I couldn't upload the Python file into Hive. Any help/suggestion will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scp` is a unix command and not a `hive` command.

Please run the same command from your **unix terminal** and it will work.

For your second problem, you can't access your windows file from your hive terminal, you can only access file which are in `hdfs`.

You cam run following command from your unix host.

```
 hdfs dfs -put <filename> <hdfs_path>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Gaurang. I am kind of new to Unix. Could you tell me where I can find the Unix terminal in my Windows?

Comment: have you installed hortoronworks sandbox or cloudera on your windows machine?

Comment: I have Hortonworks Sandbox. It is within an Oracle VM Virtualbox (not sure if it matters).

Comment: in this case, you need to open the terminal inside your windows. That's your OS where Hadoop is installed.

Comment: I see, @Gaurang Shah. I assume that terminal is the 'Hortonworks Sandbox with HDP 2.2'. It is within the Oracle VM Virtualbox. After running the unix command, I got this error message: ssh: connect to host localhost port 2222: Connection refused

Comment: i think if you trying to connect from `oracle vm` it should be port `22`

Comment: does that mean I should run the command 'scp -P 22 ~/Downloads/geohash-udf.py root@localhost:/root/' in terminal within the oracle vm? I had tried that but it still returned an error.

Comment: default port is 22 so even if you don't specify it, it's going to work. `scp ~/Downloads/geohash-udf.py root@localhost:/root/' `

Comment: Thanks, @Gaurang Shah. I tried it without '2222' and unfortunately it still won't work. It returned the 'No such file or directory' error.

Comment: @Stanleyrr `no such file or directory` measns `~/Downloads/geohash-udf.py ` is not present.